# Can i make my code shorter by removing copy pasted pieces

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a laravel project. here i have a table 'file' (id, title, desc_long, desc_short, file (like .pdf etc.), language_id) and some pivots (tags, roles)

i am able to filter these file's on, tags and language.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\File;
use App\Models\File_Role;
use App\Models\File_Tag;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ShowFile extends Component
{


    protected $listeners = ['reloadFile'];
    public function mount()
    {
        $id = Auth::user();
        $role_id = $id->role_id;
        $file_role = File_Role::where('role_id', '=', $role_id)->pluck('file_id');
        $this->files = File::whereIn('id', $file_role)->get();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.show-file');
    }

    public function reloadFile($tag_id, $query, $langs)
    {

        $this->files = File::query();

        $id = Auth::user();
        $role_id = $id->role_id;
        $file_role = File_Role::where('role_id', '=', $role_id)->pluck('file_id');
        $count = count($file_role);

        if($tag_id != 0 && $langs != 0)
        {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($file_role); $i++) {
                $fileCount = File_Tag::where('tag_id', $tag_id)->where('file_id', '=', $file_role[$i])->pluck('file_id')->count();
                $file[] = $fileCount > 0 ? File_Tag::where('tag_id', $tag_id)->where('file_id', '=', $file_role[$i])->pluck('file_id') : null;
            }
            $this->files = File::whereIn('id', $file)->where('language_id', $langs)->get(); 
        } else if ($tag_id != 0) {                
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($file_role); $i++) {
                $fileCount = File_Tag::where('tag_id', $tag_id)->where('file_id', '=', $file_role[$i])->pluck('file_id')->count();
                $file[] = $fileCount > 0 ? File_Tag::where('tag_id', $tag_id)->where('file_id', '=', $file_role[$i])->pluck('file_id') : null;
            }
            $this->files = File::whereIn('id', $file)->get();        
            
        } else if($langs != 0) {
            $this->files = File::whereIn('id', $file_role)->where('language_id', $langs)->get();

        } else {
            $this->files = File::whereIn('id',$file_role)->get();
        }


        if ($query) {
            $this->files = $this->files->where('title', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')->get();
          //  $this->files = File::whereIn('id', '=', $file_role)->get();
        }
    }
}
```

but as you can see, i use the same **FOR** loop twice. is there a way to avoid copy pasting code like i did above here?

Comment: could be a case for using a function

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: @RiggsFolly do you mean using pseudocode? or spacing between lines of code

Comment: As the comment suggested [Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/)

Comment: There's a lot more to a coding standard than just spacing, although that is certainly one aspect

Comment: Can you explain what you are try to achive in your code. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you REALLY wish to get rid of the 2nd for loop which is VERY similar to the first one, then merge these 2 if-elseif blocks into one, with two if blocks handling the differences

Change the block

```
if($tag_id != 0 && $langs != 0) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($file_role); $i++) {
        $fileCount = File_Tag::where('tag_id', $tag_id)->where('file_id', '=', $file_role[$i])->pluck('file_id')->count();
        $file[] = $fileCount > 0 ? File_Tag::where('tag_id', $tag_id)->where('file_id', '=', $file_role[$i])->pluck('file_id') : null;
    }
    $this->files = File::whereIn('id', $file)->where('language_id', $langs)->get(); 
} else if ($tag_id != 0) {                
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($file_role); $i++) {
        $fileCount = File_Tag::where('tag_id', $tag_id)->where('file_id', '=', $file_role[$i])->pluck('file_id')->count();
        $file[] = $fileCount > 0 ? File_Tag::where('tag_id', $tag_id)->where('file_id', '=', $file_role[$i])->pluck('file_id') : null;
    }
    $this->files = File::whereIn('id', $file)->get();        
        
}
```

to

```
if (($tag_id != 0 && $langs != 0) || ($tag_id != 0)){
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($file_role); $i++) {
        $fileCount = File_Tag::where('tag_id', $tag_id)->where('file_id', '=', $file_role[$i])->pluck('file_id')->count();
        $file[] = $fileCount > 0 ? File_Tag::where('tag_id', $tag_id)->where('file_id', '=', $file_role[$i])->pluck('file_id') : null;
    }
    if ($tag_id != 0 && $langs != 0){
        $this->files = File::whereIn('id', $file)->where('language_id', $langs)->get(); 
    }

    if ($tag_id != 0){
        $this->files = File::whereIn('id', $file)->where('language_id', $langs)->get(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hope you dont mind, but bad code indentation really bugs me :)

Comment: Good job @RiggsFolly.

Comment: `($tag_id != 0 && $langs != 0) || ($tag_id != 0)` is functionally identical to `($tag_id != 0)` and that could also simplify the inner cases to an `if ($langs != 0) ... else ...`